# Fixed effect of div within a parent div but position stick on screen as page scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want a DIV element fixed but relative to a parent DIV for as the screen resized that fixed DIV will move as the parents moved/resized so when you scroll down the page it will stick to that position. As i know when use position fixed on css, it will be relatively fixed to the entire screen, so the position of that fixed div will be relative to the size of your screen. What i want is that to stick or let the DIV stay to that location of the screen even if you scroll the page but its position will be relative to its parent DIV container. Is there any way to do that on CSS/Javascript/jquery?

Note: The effect should be like position:fixed where the DIV wont move when you scroll the page.

Any answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered absolute ? :)

Comment: edited, see on the note. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use `position: absolute`. You should nest the div inside a parent div. Assign `top: 0`, `left: 0`.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VdNVd/)** is the demo.

and if you want the div fixed in a location, **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VdNVd/1/)** is the demo.

Hope this helps

Comment: Where exactly is the demo? :)

Comment: sorry for not explaining it very well, but that's not what i want. what i really want is that on your example when you scroll down the page the blue DIV will stick to the screen location just like the position: fixed do.

Comment: @PHPNoob works fine in my Firefox. Which browser r u using? Its moving up with the parent div when I scroll down.